# Cannot import Python Libraries anywhere

Tags: python3

## Issue on importing Python Library

### Background

- I am on MacOS 10.14.5.
- I currently cannot import any Python third-party Library from anywhere (including VSCode, Pycharm and terminal).

---

### Detail

- For example, I have been using `pip3 install pandas` to download the Python Library:

`pip3 list`

```
Package           Version 
----------------- --------
astroid           2.2.5   
beautifulsoup4    4.7.1   
certifi           2019.3.9
chardet           3.0.4   
idna              2.8     
isort             4.3.16  
lazy-object-proxy 1.3.1   
mccabe            0.6.1   
numpy             1.16.4  
panda             0.3.1   
pandas            0.25.0
```

- However, I just cannot import it:

`python3`

```
Python 3.7.2 (v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 24 2018, 02:44:43) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas
```

- (Same problem exists in any other editor)

---

- Also, when I am trying to install Libraries by Pycharm, it reports:

  Collecting pandas

  Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: Missing dependencies for SOCKS support.
- However, even after turning off the proxy, the problem still exists.

---

If there is any other operations needed for diagnosis, please tell me!
Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

You should check where `pip` is installing Pandas and from where Python is retrieving its library.

Try:

```
pip show pandas
```

On Python try:

```
import sys
for path in sys.path:
    print(path)
```

Then check if everything is OK. You probably have more than one Python installation.

Comment: Hi, here is the return:

pip show pandas
Name: pandas
Version: 0.25.0
Summary: Powerful data structures for data analysis, time series, and statistics
Home-page: http://pandas.pydata.org
Author: None
Author-email: None
License: BSD
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: pytz, numpy, python-dateutil
Required-by:

Comment: The another return is:

Comment: python3
Python 3.7.2 (v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 24 2018, 02:44:43) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> for path in sys.path:
... print(path)
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    print(path)
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: It is just confusing. The syntax should be right, but it just reported an indentation error

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by "more than one python installing".
I have both python3 and python2 installed. However, I think I have carefully used "python3" and "pip3"..